# Caching impersonation in a C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, impersonation

I am working on an MVC web application which has to access files in various shared directories. Currently I am using this [implementation of impersonation](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation) to access a directory, which works fine. My problem starts when I have to open multiple files from the same directory, since right now I initialize a new impersonator every time and I quickly reach the number of allowed connections to the target computer.

The code right now looks like:

```
// do stuff that does not require impersonation

using (Impersonation.LogonUser("domain", "username", "password", LogonType.NewCredentials))
{
    // access **one** particular file
}

// continue doing stuff that does not require impersonation
```

However, if I use just one impersonation instance, I can access as many files as I want. This is though impractical for a web application, as I would have to run all my code under impersonation. Furthermore, different directories have different credentials (could also be located on different computers).

So my question is if it's possible to cache an impersonation, undo it for a while and re-enable it when I need to, so that I don't start a new one. Basically something like the following pseudo-code:

```
// do stuff that does not require impersonation

// get cached impersonation or create a new one
var imp = GetImpersonationFromStaticSharedCache("domain", "username", "password")
// access **one** particular file

// stop impersonation, but don't dispose it, so that I can re-use it later
imp.StopImpersonationForTheCurrentThread() 

// continue doing stuff that does not require impersonation
```

Comment: I haven't think of the details but `RevertToSelf` method(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379317(v=vs.85).aspx) should do the trick. Doesn't it?

Comment: Perhaps, but what do I cache for later re-use? And how safe (in terms of resource locking) is it to cache impersonation contexts?